# Why are "flicker flame bulbs" always bulbs or how do flicker flame bulbs work?

Tags: light

In other words, I've never seen the type of filament (if filament is the correct term—if not, what is the correct term?) outside of a bulb—as seen in the video linked to below.  Is there something about the way it works that makes them unsuitable for use when not encased in a bulb?

[Random YouTube video of the type of bulb I'm talking about.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6h7uQAe43k8)

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a StackExchange site for general electronics questions, so where else would one ask this? Looked at another way: if this site is about electronics design (as is stated above) and one were trying to design something that overcame an issue like this question asks, wouldn't this be the correct place?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Flicker Flame" bulbs are really [neon glow bulbs with specially shaped electrodes](http://ledmuseum.candlepower.us/28/neonblbs.htm).

**They are bulbs because** the neon ([with usually a little argon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penning_mixture)) must be kept pure and at low pressure.  See [*Electric discharge in gases* at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_discharge_in_gases).

**They mostly use neon** because it has breakdown/glow voltages in the range of the USA household voltage.  A [typical configuration has a breakdown voltage of around 90Vdc <sup>(Mouser datasheet, PDF)</sup>](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/423/Neon%20Indicator%20Lamps_7___8-552457.pdf) and AC sockets provide a nominal 120V<sub>rms</sub>, or 170V<sub>peak</sub>.
This minimizes the need for a serial, ballast resister (built in).

**They flicker** mostly because of [Paschen's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paschen's_law):

1. The breakdown and glow voltage [depends on electrode separation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/16461/neon-lamp-minimal-breakdown-voltage).
2. The breakdown and glow voltage depends on the pressure/density of the gas.

So, as the gas near one part of an electrode glows, it heats up -- changing its localized breakdown voltage and allowing the "flame" to move different parts of the electrodes.

Similarly, varying the electrode separation gap can encourage motion.

From [*Unstable cathode-glow and the flickering flame-effect neon*](http://www.g3ynh.info/disch_tube/lamp/flame_neon.html):

> Electrode spacing increases towards the top in this example. This gives a rising-effect in the motion of the glow spot.
>   [image: Artful electrode arrangement]

Comment: Much nicer and better explained than my educated guess. +1 I learned something again.