# Flicker flame bulb

Tags: light, incandescent

According to this [thread](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/194767/why-are-flicker-flame-bulbs-always-bulbs-or-how-do-flicker-flame-bulbs-work), flicker flame bulbs are neon glow bulbs. Consequently, they do not generate light through incandescence.

However, I have also seen bulbs marketed as flicker flame incandescent bulbs, such as [here](http://www.homedepot.com/p/GE-3-Watt-Incandescent-CA10-Bent-Tip-Clear-Flicker-Flame-Light-Bulb-3CAM-FF-CD1-TP6/100493715). What's going on?

Comment: I think "incandescent" is used in the marketing sense, rather than the physics sense.

Comment: This site says it's a neon bulb:- http://www.donsbulbs.com/cgi-bin/r/b.pl/03757.html

Comment: There is an incandescent flicker bulb with a long filament positioned above a small permanent magnet. The ac causes the filament to oscillate back & forth in the magnetic field, like a flickering candle. https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/2e/11/f0/2e11f0acd8221effa2d412fdadac946e.jpg As a side note "Aerolux" bulbs are gas discharge bulbs that produce light very efficiently. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerolux_Light_Corporation

Answer (score 0):

This is an error in home depot or the vendors information,  that's all. That bulb is a typical neon based flicker specialty bulb.